# elasticsearch filter missing field not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 65000 document in elastic-search. one field named "my_attachment" is missing in all document. I want to update documents who have this field "my_attachment" missing, so i am using query filter missing as below:

```
"query": {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "missing" : { "field" : "my_attachment" }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am doing this in way like updating document whose "my_attachment" field is missing as 10 document at time, after that query execute again and again 10 documents were updated. But on its reach 65000 documents and start again for update document. At that time this query gives result as document who have "my_attachment" field. why this happen??. Actually it will show results of whose field is missing, but i m getting result with that field. is there any issue with missing field query..? Because it works fine in one phase. i am not getting whats going there. whats wrong in that...?

Comment: Which documents give incorrect results for the `missing` filter? When were they updated? (how many seconds/minutes/hours back)

Comment: when it reach to 65000 and start again to update document, at that time missing query is not working. it shows document who have that field.