# Elasticsearch: Search Performance of index with large documents (PDF,doc,txt) is slow

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 65000 document(pdf,docx,txt,..etc) index in elastic-search using mapper-attachment. now I want to search content in that stored document using following query:

```
"from" : 0, "size" : 50,
"query": {
    "match": {
        "my_attachment.content": req.params.name
     }
}
```

but it will take 20-30 seconds for results. It is very slow response. so what i have to do for quick response? any idea?

here is mapping:

```
"my_attachment": {
                  "type": "attachment",
                  "fields": {
                     "content": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "store": true,
                        "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
                     }
                 }
}
```

Comment: You need to give us a bit more to go on that that. Do you have your mapping available to share for the index? What hardware are you trying to run this on? How much memory do you have assigned for Elasticsearch to use?

Comment: mapping type is "attachment". And i have 8gb RAM, so I have assign 4gb to elastic-search. what other thing you want to know..? and it is search in attachment file(like pdf,docsx,etc)

Comment: How big are your documents approximately? A few KBs each or more like MBs? How many nodes do you have? How many indices and how many shards (primary/replica)  per index?

Comment: both in KBs and MBs. And i have one index and five shards and no replica.

Comment: How many CPU cores and what's the querying behavior? (multiple concurrent requests or just one query execution for your testing) And what ES version?

Comment: core i5 -4440 cpu..just one query as above mention. and using single node

Comment: Ok. I'd suggest switching to 4 primary shards, which means you need to reindex. If you execute the same query multiple times, you get the slow response every time?

Comment: And you still didn't mention the ES version.

Comment: Also, run `curl localhost:9200/your_documents_index/_stats` and provide the output in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: i have 5 primary shards. And same query takes 20s - 30s for execute first time, but it will take 1s - 2s for second time.

Comment: I know you have 5 primary shards. I mentioned switching to 4 because at any given time one execution of the query will use 4 cores. And for one of the shards the query needs to wait. To have an equal distribution of load at query time, use 4 primary shards (=number of CPU cores) so that when you run the query there will not be too much contention at CPU level.

Comment: version is 2.1.1, And why it will take 1s - 2s for second time..?

Comment: Because the filter is cached. And the subsequent calls will be served from cache.

Comment: k i got it..But what about first time..? it takes so much time

Comment: Not that easy. I asked for indexing stats for that index, maybe it tells us something.

Comment: here is stats for index: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d63984f3a2c897abbb4024e296bc7f7e

Comment: Is that the complete query you are running? I see you want to have highlighting as well. Run the query with `"size" : 10` and see what time you get back.

Comment: yes its complete query. I don't need highlighting now. And run with size 10, i will get 5s - 10s. And its varies according words.

Comment: This means that part of the time spent returning the results is spent in actually bringing the documents back. From the statistics I saw that the "fetch" part (retrieving the documents from the shards) is taking 4.2 seconds per operation on average. For example, why are you storing (`"store": true`) the content?

Comment: thanks for reply. as you said fetch part taking more time. so what is solution for that..? i want quick response. And "store" : true is because of i want highlighting results in future. so how can i retrieve documents from shard as fast as possible..?

Comment: The documentation says _In order to perform highlighting, the actual content of the field is required. If the field in question is stored (has store set to true in the mapping) it will be used, otherwise, the actual _source will be loaded and the relevant field will be extracted from it._ So if you didn't disable `_source` for the index, then that will be used and storing the `content` is not necessary. Also there is no magic for having a faster fetch, it's strictly related to how large your documents are and how many you want to retrieve. Not using `store: true` might slighly improve the time

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, i will try it.!

Comment: And if you rebuild the index (you need to do that if you change the mapping) move to 4 primary shards, as well, as suggested in one of my previous comments.

Comment: ya sure. i will try it. is there anything to do..? is it actually speed of response..? for 50 documents, 20s to 30s...?

Comment: What other indices do you have in this cluster?

Comment: Also, provide the output of `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats"` in a gist.

Comment: here is output what you asked: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/24f3f919c79dc0732404426796155354

Comment: The node doesn't seem to have CPU or memory problems. And if you only run that query, I'm starting to believe that's the limit of your hardware for that specific query and amount of data.

Comment: thanks for you help. i also think that maybe problem is with resources.

Comment: Change the mapping not to store the `content`, move to 4 primary shards and test the query again. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: will you help me in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246062/elasticsearch-filter-missing-field-not-working   ??

Comment: I would try to split documents in parts (split by page, for example). This will increase your hdd usage (no problem for Elasticsearch) but will increase the search performance. Another tip that I'd implement will be extract relevant words (avoid prepositions, articles, etc) and i'll put it in a list of non-analyzed strings to query by this new field. This tip will avoid Elasticsearch to search in raw data instead of serching in plain strings (faster)

Comment: thanks @Andrei Stefan. it works.! now response time for 65000 document is below 1s(100ms-400ms). I have also disbale _source. thank you once again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your machine has 4 CPUs and the index 5 shards, I'd suggest switching to 4 primary shards, which means you need to reindex. The reason for this approach is that at any given time one execution of the query will use 4 cores. And for one of the shards the query needs to wait. To have an equal distribution of load at query time, use 4 primary shards (=number of CPU cores) so that when you run the query there will not be too much contention at CPU level.

Also, by providing the output of `curl localhost:9200/your_documents_index/_stats` I saw that the "fetch" part (retrieving the documents from the shards) is taking 4.2 seconds per operation on average. This is likely the result of having very large documents or of retrieving a lot of documents. `size: 50` is not a big number, but combined with large documents it will make the query to return the results in a longer time.

The `content` field (the one with the actual document in it) has `store: true` and if you want this for highlighting, the documentation says

> In order to perform highlighting, the actual content of the field is required. If the field in question is stored (has `store` set to `true` in the mapping) it will be used, otherwise, the actual `_source` will be loaded and the relevant field will be extracted from it.

So if you didn't disable `_source` for the index, then that will be used and storing the content is not necessary. Also there is no magic for having a faster fetch, it's strictly related to how large your documents are and how many you want to retrieve. Not using `store: true` might slighly improve the time.

From nodes stats (`curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats"`) there was no indication that the node has memory or CPU problems, so everything boils down to my previous suggestions.

Comment: but for highlighting, i have to set "store: true", because highlighting from _source gives highlighted result in "base64". so for highlighting, store: true is necessary.